# Is it possible to fight the Shadow Mewtwo final boss again after beating it once?

Tags: pokken-tournament

I beat the Shadow Mewtwo final boss before the Chroma League last night. I would like to play it again - it was a very satisfying fight!

Is there some way for me to play the boss fight again after beating it? Or am I permanently locked out of the fight from now on?

Comment: I know that Shadow Mewtwo is an unlockable character, but I'm specifically interested in the boss battle.

Comment: According to [this GameFAQs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180304-pokken-tournament/73467832), it should be possible to fight Shadow Mewtwo again. I'll have to look into this myself later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you complete the Chroma League (the fourth single-player tournament), all of the Shadow Mewtwo events become playable again and can be played whenever you wish.